# JavaScript insists that 0 is NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

So I'm making a histogram in JavaScript, and when I initialise it I have a property "contents" of each bin which is initialised to be 0:

```
for (var rBin = 0; rBin < 255; rBin += 16) {
    for (var gBin = 0; gBin < 255; gBin += 16) {
        for (var bBin = 0; bBin < 255; bBin += 16) {
            histogram[j] = {r:rBin, g:gBin, b:bBin, contents:0, width:16};
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But after this, if I log the `histogram` I get a problem that JavaScript logs `contents` and only that as NaN rather than 0:

```
0: Object
    b: 0
    contents: NaN
    g: 0
    r: 0
    width: 16
...
```

It gets weirder.  If I log only `histogram[0]` then it works correctly and gives me:

```
Object {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, contents: 0, width: 16}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The logging is done with the lines:

```
console.log(histogram);
console.log(histogram[0]);
```

EDIT2:
Pausing this in debugger shows the histogram being stored correctly on the line `console.log(histogram[0])` but not on `console.log(histogram)`...

Comment: It's probably in how you are accessing "histogram" in the first logging. Can you add that code?

Comment: The code you posted here does not do that, so you must be doing something else to the values in other code. [Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rmw4fhkw/)

Comment: Keep in mind that in some browsers at least, the console provides a "live" view of the objects you log. Should you set `contents` to `NaN` *after* logging the object, then expand the logged object, the console will update its view to show you the up-to-date values. That won't happen when you log `histogram[0]` because there is nothing to expand there.

Comment: Curious; what happens when you log an index other than 0?

Comment: @slime - it's the same for all indexes

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - would this affect why when I pause the program using debugging on one line and then another I get different values for histogram in the debugger? (See edit 2)

Comment: @Tom, technically, no. If you pause the program, say, on the second call to `log()`, then expand the results of the first call, you should see `contents` is still zero. If you don't, something very weird is happening.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - so I put breakpoints on lines logging `histogram[1]`, `histogram`, and `histogram[1]` again, and at all points the histogram that got logged said `contents` was zero.  I then removed the break points and it logged as NaN again...

Comment: @Tom, so it looks like `contents` is indeed changed later. You should double-check further operations performed on it (look for arithmetic operations mistakenly involving strings).

Comment: Ah!  @FrédéricHamidi, you nailed it - I removed a division later (I will now pursue why my integer division causes a NaN to occur) and that settled it!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: post that as an answer so we can upvote it? That seems like a really useful piece of information to have and it would be a shame for it to be lost in comments.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comments above, the console on some browsers provides a "live" view of the objects you log. For instance, Firebug will display up-to-date data when a composite object (or an array) is expanded. (Furthermore, it appears that [Chrome updates the logged information even if the user does not expand anything](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2408-chrome-dev-tools-live-update-in-the-javascript-console-is-confusing.htm).)

Therefore, at least with Firebug, logging non-expandable information (such as `histogram[0]`) will result in "static" data that will not change, while logging expandable information (such as `histogram`) will result in "dynamic" data that will reflect the state of the object at the time of expansion, not at the time of logging.

In your specific case, something in your code clobbers the value of `contents` after you have logged it, but since you're expanding the logged object you will see the clobbered values instead of the original ones.

From your comments, it looks like a division is involved. It is probably a division by zero, since `contents` is initially `0` and `0/0` yields `NaN`.